# cname redirects in asp.net white label application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, cname, white-labelling

i am developing a website like with asp.net c#

it is like a white label application

my site is www.example.com where code is hosted

clients will update their cname records to www.example.com

and whole theme, logo etc will be according to client settings
i am using code like

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s1 ="";
        s1 += "\r Host = " + Request.Url.Host;
        litr.Text = s1;
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Literal ID="litr" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

experts support needed

thanks in advance

My question is that when I am redirecting via other domain's cname value, I am getting error. The domain where my code is hosted is www.dgtads.com. I tried adding cname of dgt.gujaratcotton.com for testing.
but when i visit dgtads.com page shows ok
but when i visit dgt.gujaratcotton.com it shows following error

> You are not authorized to view this page
>
> The Web server you are attempting to reach has a list of IP addresses
>   that are not allowed to access the Web site, and the IP address of
>   your browsing computer is on this list.
>
> Please try the following:
>
> Contact the Web site administrator if you believe you should be able
>   to view this directory or page. HTTP Error 403.6 - Forbidden: IP
>   address of the client has been rejected. Internet Information Services
>   (IIS)
>
> Technical Information (for support personnel)
>
> Go to Microsoft Product Support Services and perform a title search
>   for the words HTTP and 403. Open IIS Help, which is accessible in IIS
>   Manager (inetmgr), and search for topics titled About Security,
>   Limiting Access by IP Address, IP Address Access Restrictions, and
>   About Custom Error Messages.

experts help needed in configuration of iis

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: question is that when i am redirecting via other domain's cname value i am getting error
domain on what code is hosted is www.dgtads.com
and i tried adding cname of dgt.gujaratcotton.com for testing

Comment: What error are you getting? Also I rephrased your comment and added it to the question. If I misread it, you should edit the question to clarify.

Comment: my question is where i am lacking
i need to configure my application or iis
or what is needed to do to make my app working

Comment: What you're doing and what you've shown sounds very simple, so based on what I have to go by, without seeing an error, it's impossible to help. Post the error you're getting, where does it occur, etc.

Comment: i am getting that ip is banned 403.6 error (server side error)
but i think there is some config i have to do coz dgtads.com is accessable but dgt.gujaratcotton.com is having cname of dgtads.com still it is not accessable and ip banned error occurs...
if ip is banned then when opening dgtads.com should reflect error but only dgt.gujaratcotton.com reflects error

Comment: i found a solution but its of apache
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

i wish to do this programatically

Comment: finally after lot of search i found a solution by one of my friends

get a vps server put main site on it

and then edit cnames of as many domains desired

done primary trial and it works